# Auth guard only working for default in laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, guard

I am new to laravel so please bear with me. I am trying to implement multi authentication using one login form but I am running into some trouble as the auth guard only works for the default in the auth.php file. I've tried a bunch of solutions here but they didn't seem to work. What can I do?

My auth.php file

```
<?php

return [

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],

    'employee' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'employees',
    ],
],

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],


    'employees' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Employee::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],





    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],


'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
    'employees' => [
        'provider' => 'employees',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
 ],

];
```

My LoginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

use AuthenticatesUsers;


protected $redirectTo = '/dashboard';



/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
  }
}
```

my AttemptLogin function inside the AuthenticatesUsers trait

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{

    $userAttempt = $this->guard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
    if(!$userAttempt){
        $this->checkUser = "employee";
        return $this->employeeGuard()->attempt(
            $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );

    }
    return $userAttempt;

}
```

My model

```
namespace App;


use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;



class Employee extends Authenticatable
{
use Notifiable;

    protected $guard = "employees";


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'firstname', 'surname', 'DOB', 'gender', 'mobile_number', 
'job_title','job_sector', 
    'highest_qualification', 'experience', 'short_description', 
'relocation_willingness', 
    'salary_range', 'city', 'cv', 'five_tag_summation', 'email', 
'password',
];


protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];



protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
}
```

my routes

```
 Route::get('/', 'PagesController@index');

Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');

Route::get('/services', 'PagesController@services');

Route::get('/blog', 'PagesController@blog');

Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');

Route::resource('jobs', 'JobsController');

Route::get('/users/{id}/{name}', function ($id, $name) {
    return "This is user ".$id." with the name ".$name;
});

Route::get('/employeeRegister', 'Auth\EmployeeRegController@showRegistration');


Route::post('/employeeRegister', 'Auth\EmployeeRegController@register')->name('employeeRegister');

Auth::routes();


Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index');
```

Comment: What does method `employeeGuard()` look like?

Comment: It just returns Auth::guard("employee") :

Comment: Does `Employee` have its own table? When a user or employee registers do you place the records in the same table or a different table?

Comment: Different tables. The User has its own model. So there are two tables but I'm trying to authenticate them through one login form. So far everything has worked except the auth.php part that's only working for the default. But I know it's seeing the employee table because when I try to login with correct employee details it doesn't say my details are incorrect, it just refreshes the login page..

Comment: What does your `"EmployeesProvider"` look like from `'provider' => 'employees'`?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your configuration, you can start debugging by dumping values from `retrieveByCredentials` and `validateCredentials` in `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider`